# Display Substring in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to extract a part of the string of a column in the column. For example: i have a table "Employee" and want to display actual error message in error column.

[image]

Required:

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance for all replies.

Comment: SUBSTRING('abcdef', 2, 3);

Answer (score 1):

If you just have 1 "Error" in your errors tag and the column cotains valid xml then you can try this:

```
select ID, [Name], Cast([Error] AS XML).value('(/errors/Error)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Error
FROM t
```

Here you find a small [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1dd9b/6).

Comment: Tjasun, column does not contain valid xml tag. you can consider the value as string.

Answer (score 0):

you should make one common function to strip Error tags,

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML] (@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
```

By making this function, call like this

**select dbo.[udf_StripHTML] ('your string with tags')**

Comment: Rajesh, column values are not valid html tags.

Comment: @curiousboy - I know, but it will remove any tag which has symbol "<" and ">". Also, I have tried with your column data and it is working fine. it is giving as per your required result. please try dude...

Comment: Ouch a scalar function with a while loop. This will work but the performance is going to be pretty slow.